# Conflict between conditions

Tags: c

When I insert in my source code the following block of instructions:

```
while(qx < xmin || qx > xmax){
    if(qx > xmax)
        qx = 2 * xmax - qx;
    if(qx < xmin)
        qx = 2 * xmin - qx;
}
```

the compiler does not return any error, but the execution does not come to an end. `qx` is a float value, `xmax` and `xmin` are integer values.

What should I fix?

[updated from comment]:

xmin = 0, xmax = 200 and qx is a random value.

Comment: You might like to change `2` to become `2.`.

Comment: You might want to change your example to be an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @alk: that shouldn't change a thing.

Comment: I removed the bracket.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: It makes sure the multiplication won't overflow, at least not by hitting the integer maximum.

Comment: xmin = 0, xmax = 200 and qx is a random value.

Comment: @alk Oh I see, xmax/xmin are ints. Good point.

Comment: hmmm .. replace the `while` with an `if` ...

Comment: qx is a random value between what bounds?

Comment: By my sense of symmetry I feel the second clause should add `qx`.

Comment: You'll certainly have a problem for `xmin > 0` and `qx = 0`.

Comment: @user3482381 you should limit the range of `qx` to start with. In the current case what will happen if `qx` is a very big number? say 1000000, how may iteration the loop going to run? have you waited long enough?

Comment: @ThanushanBalakrishnan for qx > 0: `qx / (2 * xmax)` = 2500 iterations. for qx < 0: `1 + qx / 2 * xmax)` iterations. Atleast for xmin=0.

Comment: So, what is the range of `qx` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a debugger or a `printf` in the loop body to see what the value of qx is becoming and fix your logic.  Since you never told us what you're trying to compute, this is about the only possible answer.

One thing it could be is floating point precision. If `qx` is a `float`, it has at most 9 digits of precision.  So if it's initial random value is more than 10^11 or so, the `2*xmax` term disappears into round-off error, and `qx` will oscillate between +10^11 and -10^11 forever.

Comment: How does `xmin = 1, xmax = 2, qx = 3` not terminate? First iteration: `qx > xmax => qx = 2*xmax-qc = 2*2-3 = 1`. qx is now 1, the while-condition isn't true anymore and it immediately terminates?

Comment: @ccKep  Thanks.  Looked at this too quickly at lunchtime.  More plausible case is there now.